# How can I add a CORS header to this Lambda function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Please bare with me as this is my first stack overflow post, but I have minimal backend experience and am really struggling to meet CORS requirements.

I want to use AWS (SES, API Gateway, Lambda) to send form data to our company email account. My function works currently when testing in AWS, but it doesn't work on the client side of my site. From what I've gathered from research so far, my Lambda function needs a CORS header to work.  Here is the code:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });

exports.handler = async function(payload) {
  var params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ['placeholder@place.com'],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: `\n
        ${payload.fullName} has tried to contact you. \n
        Message: \n
        -------------------- \n
        ${payload.comments} \n
        -------------------- \n
        Here is the sender's contact information: \n 
        Name: ${payload.fullName} \n
        Email: ${payload.emailAddress} \n
        Phone: ${payload.phone} \n
        Company: ${payload.companyName}`
        },
      },

      Subject: { Data: payload.subject },
    },
    Source: 'placeholder@place.com',
  };


  return ses.sendEmail(params).promise()
};
```

I'm looking at this code as an example of how to include a CORS header:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let data = {};
  let res =  {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' // replace with hostname of frontend (CloudFront)
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  return res;
};
```

Can anyone help me to combine these two approaches? I don't understand how to make the SES function into a more traditional response. I am mostly a frontend dev, so I expect that I'm missing something silly. I appreciate any responses though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the API Gateway integration type to [Lambda Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), then this code can help you.

Move the entire code in the handler method to another function say `sendEmail`

```
const sendEmail =  async function(payload) {
  // Your code to crete the `params` omitted for brevity
  return ses.sendEmail(params).promise()
};
```

The handler can call this function and based on the outcome of this function send an appropriate result with the CORS headers

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  const payload = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const CORS_HEADERS = { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' // Your origin name
  };
  try {
    await sendEmail(payload);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: CORS_HEADERS,
      body: '{}'
    }
  } catch(err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500, // Can be 4XX or 5XX depending on the error
      headers: CORS_HEADERS,
      body: `{"err": ${err.messge}}`
    }
  }
}
```

For this to work for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) requests, you also need to ensure the `OPTIONS` request responds with appropriate headers. You can do so using the AWS console following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) documentation. For CloudFormation along with api-gateway V2, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigatewayv2-api-cors.html) documentation should help. For AWS SAM, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-corsconfiguration.html) documentation should help (If you are not already using any Serverless development tool, take a look at AWS [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/)).

If you don't wish to use the Lambda proxy, then ensure the integration response send the appropriate CORS headers for both the OPTIONS request and the POST  request. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html) can help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used your code suggestion but decided against all the AWS/CORS hoops. I setup a new HTML API Gateway following [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-receive-emails-via-your-sites-contact-us-form-with-aws-ses-lambda-api-gateway/) and everything works now!